# How to transfer existing WordPress website to new multisite wordpress domain?

Tags: multisite

**First time Working with WordPress multisite feature.**

I have 2 domains:

1) www.one.com 
2) www.two.com

Now I have successfully setup multisite feature in **www.one.com**. My need is to merge **www.two.com** site as multisite with **www.one.com** and url shhould be **www.one.com/two/**

Now can you tell me how I can access **www.two.com** on **www.one.com/two/** domain?

What is the best way to do this?

I have the backup of **www.two.com** domain all files and DB.

**Your help is highly appreciated!**